# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Хочу написать тг бота но

Когда я пытаюсь взять данные из таблицы PostgreSql Вылазит ошибка

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column 'username' does not exist
```

Но username это не столбец а переменная

```
username = message.from_user.username
```

Вот как выглядит sql-запрос:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT money FROM bank WHERE username=%s' % user)
```

Я не знаю в чем проблема, перерыл пол интернета но нечего не нашел..

Comment: как же не столбец, если вы именно так к нему и обращаетесь в запросе `WHERE username=`

Comment: вопрос и закрыть не закрыли. и ответить не ответили...

Comment: вы разобрались с данным вопросом?